# how to find the application of ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

This question may be out of the scope of this website, if so let me know and i will delete it. so I am right now taking an ODE class, which i find to be mildly interesting, though it seems to be more abstract than calculus.. so i am wondering does any one have any advice on how to make it more interesting. for instance when i was in calculus I found it to be fun, because i could use the shell method for example to find the area of actual shapes... or find the velocity vector from the position function. the point is i could see clear applications. so I am wondering if any one has any advice on how I can make ODE more enjoyable by actually using it for practical things? I have seen the population model and the mixing problems, but I don't really understand where that would be applied. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about solving Newton's equations of motion ? This wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation) lists several interesting examples

Comment: I'm sure your teacher would be happy to point you in the direction of any number of books full of applications of ODEs.

Comment: Physics is all about solving differential equations. Newton's law $F=ma$ *is* a differential equation. They're everywhere! Here's one popular application: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link](http://www.math.ncsu.edu/mmc/ma341lectures.php) to video lectures on Applied Differential Equations at NC State U. [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130400971) to Applied Differential Equations by Murray Spiegel, at amazon. [Link](http://www.uah.edu/howell/DEtext/index.htm) to the text for Applied Differential Equations at U Alabama. Big chunks of Differential Equations and their Applications by Martin Braun are available at Google Books.

Comment: thank you very much! this is very helpful.